# Monodevelop - BitBucket - Malformed URL

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, monodevelop, malformed

I am currently using Monodevelop 5.10 and Git 2.7.0.rc3 under Debian Sid.

I have private repository on BitBucked but when i try to push (or download it (checkout)) it cancels with "Malformed URL".

I tried to use Google but it didn't found anything.

Comment: [URL by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/definition.html) and I didn't use any URL in configuring Version Control except `https://AbitDeveloper@bitbucket.org/...`

Comment: can you include a screenshot of MonoDevelop showing you the error?

Comment: When I setup repository (because I deleted .git folder when trying to repair that) I see [all of these windows/messages](http://i.imgur.com/0CPc4Q4.png). Of course I fill it but I don't want to share my personal informations.